# "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта" при попытке удаления строки в datagridview c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

В dataGridView1 расположена таблица из бд с 11 столбцами + отдельно прописан столбец "Удалить" через linkcell.  Сейчас пытаюсь прописать код, чтобы при нажатии на эту ссылку удалялась строка.
Собственно, вот её код:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {            
                if (e.ColumnIndex == 11)
                {
                    string execute = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[11].Value.ToString();

                    if (execute == "Delete")
                    {
                        if (MessageBox.Show("Удалить этот заказ?", "Удаление", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
                        {
                            int rowIndex = e.RowIndex;
                            dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(rowIndex);
                            dataSet.Tables["Заказы"].Rows[rowIndex].Delete();
                            sqlDataAdapter.Update(dataSet, "Заказы");
                        }
                    }                    
                }
        }
```

Через отладчик поймал ошибку здесь
`dataSet.Tables["Заказы"].Rows[rowIndex].Delete();`
Изначально думал, что ошибка в том, что с этой таблицей по внешнему ключу связана вторая таблица. Прописал в ВК on delete cascade on update cascade, всё обновил, но ошибка всё равно вылезает.
В чём может быть причина?
Rows.Count = 4, при удалении последней строки (как раз-таки четвёртой) rowIndex = 3.

Comment: А через отладчик не посмотрили, сколько там `Rows.Count` и какое значение у `RowIndex`?

Comment: @aepot при попытке удалить 4 (последнюю заполненную) строчку выходит так: Rows.Count = 4, rowIndex = 3

Comment: Добавьте эту информацию в вопрос, отредактируйте его. Если вы говорите все как есть, что у `dataSet.Tables["Заказы"]` 4 строки, а вы пытаетесь удалить третью, то должно все работать.

Comment: Из DGV удалять ничего не нужно. Удаляйте только из `DataTable`.

Comment: @Bulson Убрал эту строчку с удалением из грида `dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(rowIndex);`, и всё равно вылезает та же самая ошибка на той же самой строчке System.NullReferenceException: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."

System.Data.DataTableCollection.this[string].get вернул null.

Answer (score 0):

Пример не на Access, но сути это не меняет

```
public partial class FormMain : Form
{
    private const string _conString = @"Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;" +
                                  "Initial Catalog=DatabaseOneTable;" +
                                  "Integrated Security=True;";
    private const string _selectString = "SELECT * FROM People";
    private readonly DataTable _dataTable;

    public FormMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _dataTable = new DataTable();
        this.Load += FormMain_Load;
    }

    private void FormMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var adp = new SqlDataAdapter(_selectString, _conString))
            {
                //читаем данные заполняем данными таблицу
                int countRecords = adp.Fill(_dataTable);
                Trace.WriteLine($"Прочитано {countRecords}");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        _dataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        _dataGridView.DataSource = _dataTable;
        _dataGridView.CellClick += DataGridView_CellClick;
    }

    private void DataGridView_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        //проверяем, что кликнули по нужного типа ячейке
        var linkCell = _dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex] as DataGridViewLinkCell;
        if (linkCell == null)
            return;

        var id = (int)_dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["_columnId"].Value;
        var row = _dataTable.AsEnumerable().First(r => r.Field<int>("Id") == id);
        //удаляем
        row.Delete();
        try
        {
            //обновляем в БД (команду DELETE строит билдер)
            using (var adp = new SqlDataAdapter(_selectString, _conString))
            using (var cmb = new SqlCommandBuilder(adp))
            {
                var deleted = adp.Update(_dataTable);
                Trace.WriteLine($"Удалено {deleted}");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```